# How to redirect Apache on LimitRequestBody?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have this line in my .htaccess file which is working very fine(limiting POST to 1mb):

```
LimitRequestBody 2048000
```

But my problem is - if the POST has exceeded 2mb, Apache throws an error and I would like it to show **custom error message** or to **redirect** to some page.

I believe this can be somehow achieved with **rewrite engine** but don't know how. 
Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need mod_rewrite, you just need to use `ErrorDocument` and direct 413 (Request Entity Too Large) to your custom error message:

Something like:

```
ErrorDocument 413 /custom-message.php
```